# Custom URL For BigCartel Custom Page

Tags: html, css, url, bigcartel, custom-url

Is there a way to change the URL to a custom page? For Example - If I title the page "The Brand", the URL will automatically be mystoreurl.com/the-brand. What if I want it at mystoreurl.com/brand?

Or what if I title a page "Frequently Asked Questions" - how do I get the link to be /faq instead of the auto-generated /frequently-asked-questions?

I see that there is this code at the top - would that help?

```
<body id="{{ page.permalink }}" class="{{ page.category }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from scratch:

1. Create a new page and name it whatever you wish the link to be.
2. Press done and then publish.
3. Return to the custom page
4. Rename the page title to whatever you wish the page title to be.
5. Press done and then publish.

That should do it!